# How can I estimate the stack space needed to turn an infix expression into a postfix expression

Tags: algorithm, stack, estimation, shunting-yard

There is the famous [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) that can be used to turn an infix expression (such as `1 + 2 * 3`) into a postfix expression (such as `1 2 2 * +`). The shunting-yard algorithm needs a stack to store elements that are about to be moved.

Is it possible to pre-estimate the length of the stack needed to perform a translation of a specific input into its postfix form in linear time and constant memory?

Comment: would running the shunting yard algorithm on the input but counting instead of pushing and popping the operators qualify as an answer?

Comment: @groovy IIRC you need to know the contents of the stack to probably run shunting yard, say, if you have parens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  The [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) only pushes operators (including parentheses) onto the stack, so a first-order approximation is the number of operators in the expression.  With a little more intelligence, you could scan the expression and look for associativity and grouping.  But by the time you were done, you would probably have written a stack-based algorithm for determining the best estimate of the stack size required for the expression, and would have doubled your execution cost.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'd like to do this estimation because I want to avoid a recursive algorithm. I already have to go through the infix expression before to estimate something else, so I think it is a simple optimization to save calls to malloc by precalculating the stack size I need.

Comment: The shunting-yard algorithm is non-recursive.  An algorithm is not recursive just because it uses a stack as a data structure.  And using a stack as a data structure is **much** less memory-intensive than using recursive calls.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. That's why I use Shunting yard instead of rolling out a recursive parser. I'd just like to preestimate the amount of stack needed to avoid repeated calls to malloc.

Answer (score 0):

On the old HP-45 calculator we always scanned for the most deeply nested parentheses, and started evaluation there. That should be a quick O(N) algorithm for N tokens in the input.

In practice, it was challenging to create an expression that blew the 4-high stack of the HP-45.

Comment: Thank you for the answer although I can't really see how this is related to the shunting yard algorithm.